# filesize() stat failed for function to get ID3 tags of MP3 file

Tags: php, id3

It works with local files but not with external domains. Here's my code (which I got from http://www.barattalo.it/2010/02/22/reading-mp3-informations-with-php-id3-tags/):

```
<?
function tagReader($file){
$id3v23 = array("TIT2","TALB","TPE1","TRCK","TDRC","TLEN","USLT");
$id3v22 = array("TT2","TAL","TP1","TRK","TYE","TLE","ULT");
$fsize = filesize($file);
$fd = fopen($file,"r");
$tag = fread($fd,$fsize);
$tmp = "";
fclose($fd);
if (substr($tag,0,3) == "ID3") {
    $result['FileName'] = $file;
    $result['TAG'] = substr($tag,0,3);
    $result['Version'] =    hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,3,1))).".".hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,4,1)));
}
if($result['Version'] == "4.0" || $result['Version'] == "3.0"){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v23);$i++){
        if (strpos($tag,$id3v23[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
            $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v23[$i].chr(0));
            $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+5),3)));
            $data = substr($tag, $pos, 10+$len);
            for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
                $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
            }
            if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TIT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,4);
            if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TALB") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,4);
            if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TPE1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,4);
            if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TRCK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,4);
            if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TDRC") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,4);
            if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TLEN") $result['Length'] = substr($tmp,4);
            if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "USLT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,7);
            $tmp = "";
        }
    }
}
if($result['Version'] == "2.0"){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v22);$i++){
        if (strpos($tag,$id3v22[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
            $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v22[$i].chr(0));
            $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+3),3)));
            $data = substr($tag, $pos, 6+$len);
            for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
                $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
            }
            if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,3);
            if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TAL") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,3);
            if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TP1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,3);
            if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TRK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,3);
            if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TYE") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,3);
            if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TLE") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,3);
            if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "ULT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,6);
            $tmp = "";
        }
    }
}
return $result;
}
$song = tagReader("file.mp3");
echo $song[Title];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works only with local files. You cant pass remote mp3 file as parameter of this function and that is senseless. Files open with [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) so they must be local files. Same thing for [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php).

```
  $fsize = filesize($file);
  $fd = fopen($file,"r");
```

What  exactly you want to load with this function? What do you mean with "It doesn't work with external domains"?

This line should work only with `file.mp3` stored in same directory as this script.

```
  $song = tagReader("file.mp3");
```

If you can't read local file, than you should check READ permission for that file.

Same reason why [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) probably don't work.

Suggestion: You should use quotes for alphanumeric array indexes...

```
  echo $song['Title']; // or 
  echo $song["Title"];
```

instead of

```
  echo $song[Title];
```

Yes, it probably works, but still, you should not do that. I suggest using single quotes to avoid evaluation of variable names in some specific cases (as array indexes such as `$array['$index']`).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'm just starting to learn the ropes of php...

Could I use something like file_get_contents() instead? Or is there another way to store the file locally temporarily? I know I could use curl to wget but I can't run shell commands on my server.

Comment: Or maybe just download the first part of the file? All the info I need is right at the beginning...

Comment: @robbiest, file_get_contents() can help you to get remote file and than use this function after download. About ID3v2... yes, it's at the beginning of file-stream (ID3v1 is at the end) but you don't know size of tag data. ID3v2 is not that simple as ID3v1 and it may contain more than this few fields (120+). Sometimes it may contain very large amount of data and tags you want may be near the end of tag-stream. You should learn PHP better and how to deal inside the streams and you'll be able to write your own ID3v2 extractor following [official id3v2 documentation](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0).

Comment: @robbiest, just want to say, it's not that easy task, like you might think. I'm curious, why do you want to read remote files? Do you have permission of its owner(s) to do that (that may be illegal like downloading from YouTube). Just be aware of it.